# Problema con Form carga de files Extjs

Tags: extjs

Quiero que capture un archivo `rpt` en la parte del diseño mas que nada, tengo 2 `fileuploadfield` se muestran de la siguiente manera.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como pueden ver queda un espacio demasiado grande entre el `button` y la caja este es el código que tengo:

```
var formRegistroRecepT = new Ext.FormPanel({
    id: 'formRegistroRecepT',
    region: 'center',
    height: 300,
    width: 800,
    border: false,
    labelWidth: 50,
    margins: { top: 0, right: 5, bottom: 5, left: 5 },
    items: [
            { xtype: 'displayfield', hideLabel: true, height: 10 },
            { xtype: 'compositefield', hideLabel: true, combineErrors: false, items: [{ xtype: 'displayfield', width: 10 }, lblTipoRecepcionRRT, chkTipoRRT, { xtype: 'displayfield', value: '', width: 2 }, lblVerPortalRRT, txtVerPortalRRT] },
            { xtype: 'compositefield', hideLabel: true, combineErrors: false, items: [{ xtype: 'displayfield', width: 10 }, lblValidacionRRT, chkValidacionRRAT, chkValidacionRRAriT, chkValidacionRRDT, chkValidacionRROT, { xtype: 'displayfield', value: '', width: 2 }, lblDescOtroT, txtDescOtroT] },
            { xtype: 'compositefield', hideLabel: true, combineErrors: false, items: [{ xtype: 'displayfield', width: 10 }, lblVerMonitoreoRRT, txtVerMonitoreoRRT, { xtype: 'displayfield', value: '', width: 50 }, lblVerArchivosRRT, txtVerArchivosRRT] },
            { xtype: 'compositefield', hideLabel: true, combineErrors: false, items: [{ xtype: 'displayfield', width: 10 }, lblVerBDRRT, txtVerBDRRT, { xtype: 'displayfield', value: '', width: 50 }, lblBDIntRRT, rdBDInterRRT] },
            { xtype: 'compositefield', hideLabel: true, combineErrors: false, items: [{ xtype: 'displayfield', width: 10 }, { xtype: 'displayfield', value: '', width: 50}] },
            { xtype: 'compositefield', hideLabel: true, combineErrors: false, items: [{ xtype: 'displayfield', width: 10 }, lblWsRRT, rdWsRRT, { xtype: 'displayfield', value: '', width: 50 }, lblNombreWsRRT, txtWsRRT] },
            { xtype: 'compositefield', hideLabel: true, combineErrors: false, items: [{ xtype: 'displayfield', width: 10 }, lblComentariosERT, txtComentariosRRT] },
            { xtype: 'compositefield', hideLabel: true, combineErrors: false, height: 10, items: [{ xtype: 'displayfield', width: 10}] },
            { xtype: 'fileuploadfield', id: 'fieldRptGT', emptyText: 'Seleccionar archivo rpt...', vtype: 'validaExtensionRpt', fieldLabel: 'Rpt Genérico', buttonText: '', buttonCfg: { iconCls: 'upload-icon'} },
            { xtype: 'fileuploadfield', id: 'fieldRptVT', emptyText: 'Seleccionar archivo rpt...', vtype: 'validaExtensionRpt', fieldLabel: 'Rpt Validación', buttonText: '', buttonCfg: { iconCls: 'upload-icon'} }
    ],
    bbar: [btnGuardarRR, '|', btnEditarRegistroR]
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Resolví el detalle agregando un filedset de esta manera.

```
var formRegistroRecepT = new Ext.FormPanel({
        id: 'formRegistroRecepT',
        region: 'center',
        height: 300,
        width: 800,
        border: false,
        labelWidth: 100,
        margins: { top: 0, right: 5, bottom: 5, left: 5 },
        items: [
                { xtype: 'displayfield', hideLabel: true, height: 10 },
                { xtype: 'compositefield', hideLabel: true, combineErrors: false, items: [{ xtype: 'displayfield', width: 10 }, lblTipoRecepcionRRT, chkTipoRRT, { xtype: 'displayfield', value: '', width: 2 }, lblVerPortalRRT, txtVerPortalRRT] },
                { xtype: 'compositefield', hideLabel: true, combineErrors: false, items: [{ xtype: 'displayfield', width: 10 }, lblValidacionRRT, chkValidacionRRAT, chkValidacionRRAriT, chkValidacionRRDT, chkValidacionRROT, { xtype: 'displayfield', value: '', width: 2 }, lblDescOtroT, txtDescOtroT] },
                { xtype: 'compositefield', hideLabel: true, combineErrors: false, items: [{ xtype: 'displayfield', width: 10 }, lblVerMonitoreoRRT, txtVerMonitoreoRRT, { xtype: 'displayfield', value: '', width: 50 }, lblVerArchivosRRT, txtVerArchivosRRT] },
                { xtype: 'compositefield', hideLabel: true, combineErrors: false, items: [{ xtype: 'displayfield', width: 10 }, lblVerBDRRT, txtVerBDRRT, { xtype: 'displayfield', value: '', width: 50 }, lblBDIntRRT, rdBDInterRRT] },
                { xtype: 'compositefield', hideLabel: true, combineErrors: false, items: [{ xtype: 'displayfield', width: 10 }, { xtype: 'displayfield', value: '', width: 50}] },
                { xtype: 'compositefield', hideLabel: true, combineErrors: false, items: [{ xtype: 'displayfield', width: 10 }, lblWsRRT, rdWsRRT, { xtype: 'displayfield', value: '', width: 50 }, lblNombreWsRRT, txtWsRRT] },
                { xtype: 'compositefield', hideLabel: true, combineErrors: false, items: [{ xtype: 'displayfield', width: 10 }, lblComentariosERT, txtComentariosRRT] },
                { xtype: 'compositefield', hideLabel: true, combineErrors: false, height: 10, items: [{ xtype: 'displayfield', width: 10}] },
                { xtype: 'fieldset', title: 'Archivos', autoHeight: true, height: 200,  defaults: { anchor: '100%' },
                    items:[
                        { xtype: 'fileuploadfield', id: 'fieldRptGT', emptyText: 'Seleccionar archivo rpt...', vtype: 'validaExtensionRpt', fieldLabel: 'Rpt Genérico', buttonText: '', buttonCfg: { iconCls: 'upload-icon'} },
                        { xtype: 'fileuploadfield', id: 'fieldRptVT', emptyText: 'Seleccionar archivo rpt...', vtype: 'validaExtensionRpt', fieldLabel: 'Rpt Validación', buttonText: '', buttonCfg: { iconCls: 'upload-icon'} }
                    ]
                }
        ],
        bbar: [btnGuardarRR, '|', btnEditarRegistroR]
    });
```